# Aggregate FileSize data info

Tags: mysql

I'm building a database that's containing a few million records of file metadata.

The **Files** table is as following:

| Name | FileSize |
| --- | --- |
| a.txt | 1000 |
| b.txt | 2000 |
| etc | etc |

I'm looking to get data on how many files exist in a specific range like this:

| Size | NumberOfFiles |
| --- | --- |
| 0-1 KB | 1000 |
| 1-4 KB | 2000 |
| 4-10 KB | 3000 |
| etc | etc |
| Larger | 5000 |

I'm a bit stuck though on counting the results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
CASE
WHEN FileSize between 0 and 1000 then ' 0-1 KB'
WHEN FileSize between 1001 and 4000 then ' 1-4 KB'
WHEN FileSize between 4001 and 10000 then ' 4-10 KB'
ELSE ' Larger' END as Size
FROM Files
GROUP BY Size
```

When I add the `COUNT(*)` the statement fails. I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Add a `,` after `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Is there any error message you want to share?

Comment: Adding the comma solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can do it through `IF` just like this:

```
SELECT count(*),  
       IF(f.size>5000,'larger',  -- if f.size>5000 returns larger
       IF(f.size>3000,'4-10 KB', -- else if f.size>3000 returns 4-10 KB
       IF(f.size>2000,'1-4 KB',  -- else if f.size>2000 returns 1-4 KB
                      '0-1 KB')  -- else returns 0-1 KB
      )) as size
FROM files AS f 
GROUP BY size; -- order by the `size` alias
```

Comment: I can also confirm that this works! Thanks!